# Use a function with default and extra arguments

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js

I'm learning D3 and I'm looking the way to define a function with the arguments (d,i) and an extra argument "arg". The problem is that later I need to call it using the argument "arg" and it doesn't work for any reason, here I let an example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>my first d3</title>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var data = [10, 20, 30, 40];

    var arg = 10;

    var lis = d3.select("body")
      .append("ul")
      .selectAll("li")
      .data(data)

    lis.enter()
      .append("li")
      .text(example(d, i, arg))

    function example(d, i, arg) {
      var c = i + arg;
      return "item n° " + c + " has value: " + d
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Note that without "arg" and calling it just like "example" it works. Thanks!

Comment: We can only properly help you if you create an [MCVE] showing us where the function is defined and where you'll call it. It doesn't need to be your code, just a very simplified (running) version.

Comment: ok thanks! I made a new example complete and verifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this...

```
.text(example(d, i, arg))
```

... you're calling `example` immediately (with variables that don't exist) and passing its result to the `text()` method, which is not what you want. As you already know...

> Note that without "arg" and calling it just like "example" it works.

That's because...

```
.text(example)
```

... is the same of:

```
.text(function(d, i, n){
    return example(d, i, n);
})
```

... where `d`, `i` and `n` are the default arguments passed to the anonymous function.

So, if you want to use the `datum` and the `index` passed by default to the anonymous function inside the `text()` method, you have to wrap the call to `example` inside that anonymous function:

```
  .text(function(d, i) {
      return example(d, i, arg)
  })
```

Here is your code with that change:

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>my first d3</title>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var data = [10, 20, 30, 40];

    var arg = 10;

    var lis = d3.select("body")
      .append("ul")
      .selectAll("li")
      .data(data)

    lis.enter()
      .append("li")
      .text(function(d, i) {
        return example(d, i, arg)
      })

    function example(d, i, arg) {
      var c = i + arg;
      return "item n° " + c + " has value: " + d
    }
  </script>
</body>
```